# Postfix keeps inserting misplaced delimiter!

Tags: 18.04, postfix

```
Setting up postfix (3.3.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
setting myhostname=akhilesh-Predator-G3-571..name in /etc/postfix

Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with the changes above.  If you need to make 
changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'service postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: akhilesh-Predator-G3-571..name
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: akhilesh-Predator-G3-571..name
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I keep changing myhostname to a valid name, say 'akhilesh' and run:

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Again postfix will change it to the above name, or add "..name".
What is the catch here?

Comment: Is it an option for you to set the correct hostname system-wide in `/etc/hostname`? That would be the proper thing to do.

Comment: Changed in /etc/hostname. But this is what I get:                                          Setting up postfix (3.3.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
setting myhostname=akhilesh..name in /etc/postfix

Postfix (main.cf) is now set up with the changes above.  If you need to make 
changes, edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'service postfix reload'.

Comment: I have changed it to "akhilesh". But the thing is, it keeps adding "..name" in the end to my hostname, and newaliases will make it invalid.

Comment: You need to reboot for the hostname change to take effect (or set the hostname manually with `sudo hostname <your hostname>`).

Comment: By the way, is `myhostname` defined in your `main.cf`. On most systems, it isn't and the default value (which is the actual hostname) is used.

Comment: `echo $HOSTNAME` gives me `akhilesh` as output. I deleted main.cf, and the new one has `myhostname=akhilesh..name` since postfix is adding '..name' at the end to my hostname, for some unknown reason.

Comment: That is very weird; could you paste the full contents of your `main.cf` (with private details obscured if you wish)?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n5Ch3CV3

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `myhostname=akhilesh.name` (hostname with domain ".name" (or ".localdomain")).
Next, run `sudo service postfix reload`.
It changed myhostname value and solved error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Static hostname: xps.lin.com
Chassis: laptop
Operating System: Ubuntu 21.04
Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-25-generic
Architecture: x86-64
```

I had the same problem as you, but after I changed my hostname from `xps` to `xps.lin.com` the problem fixed.

So I think the hostname should have a format of `*.*.*`, and that's why the system keep adding `..` to your hostname to compliance with that format.